# Reactjs: Accessing 'this' of a sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation where I have 3 components; `<View>` `<Content>` and `<Footer>`.

`<View>` is parent of `<Content>` and `<Footer>`. Now there is a button in `<Footer>` and when it is clicked, I want to render an `Overlay` in the `<Content>` component, so i have to have access to `this` of the `<Content>` component inside my `<Footer>` component. I am not getting on how to accomplish that.

`View.js`

```
class View extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Content messages={this.props.messages}/>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`Content.js`

```
class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.messages}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

`Footer.js`

```
class Footer extends Component {
  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.state = {
      showEmojiPicker: false,
    }
  }

  handleToggleEmojiPicker() {
    this.setState({
      showEmojiPicker: !this.state.showEmojiPicker,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <bootstrap.Button ref="targetEmojiPicker" bsSize="xsmall" onClick={this.handleToggleEmojiPicker.bind(this)}>
              <bootstrap.Glyphicon glyph="heart" />
            </bootstrap.Button>
              <bootstrap.Overlay
                  show={this.state.showEmojiPicker}
                  onHide={this.handleClose.bind(this)}
                  container={content.this}  //Need this of Content component
                  target={() => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.targetEmojiPicker)}
              >
              <EmojiModalCategories actions={this.props.actions}/>
            </bootstrap.Overlay>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }

}
```

Comment: *"so i have to access the `this` of `<Content>` component inside my `<Footer>` component."* No. Instead, `Footer` should accept a callback to notify its "parent" (`<View>`) that the button was clicked. `<View>` can then update its state, rerender and pass different props or children to `<Content>` that make it render the overlay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a read at the [Communicate between components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) page of the official React documentation.

If you want to access a function in the `Content` component from the `Footer` you'll have to supply that function as a `prop` to your `Footer` from the `View`.

Assume you want to run the `showOverlay()` function that's in your `Content` component, you could do:

#### View

```
displayOverlay = () => {
  this.refs.content.showOverlay();
}

render() {
  //some code
  <Content ref="content" />
  //some code
  <Footer overlayButtonClick={this.displayOverlay} />
}
```

#### Footer

```
btnClick = () => {
  this.props.overlayButtonClick();
}    

render() {
  //some code
  <button onClick={this.btnClick}>Click</button>
  //some code
}
```

---

**Edit August 2017**

Note that using string literals for `ref` value is now deprecated. For more info, you may have a look at an earlier answer I made, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873736/2030321).

Comment: yeah did the same thing you said, i'll post an answer to clarify the scenario how i achieved it. Anyway I'll mark yours as correct answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Redux Or Flux better approach would be dispatch some action 'DISPLAY_OVERLAY'. change some reducer or store value to true for example `reducer.displayOverlay=true`; and then use that reducer value in your **Content** component's render method.

```
  render:function(){
    return <div>
    {reducer.displayOverLay? this.showOverlay():this.hideOverlay()}
    </div>
    }
```

if you are not using flux or redux then make use of your view component    state. set a state variable `showOverlay:false` in your view components state. then pass that `showOverlay` down to `Content` component

```
<Content showOverlay={this.state.showOverlay}/>
```

then

**View**

```
toggleOverLay(){
   this.setState({
       showOverlay:!this.state.showOverlay
    })
}
render() {
  //some code
  <Content showOverlay={this.state.showOverlay}/>
  //some code
  <Footer toggleOverlay={this.toggleOverlay} />
}
```

**Footer**

```
 btnClick = () => {
  this.props.toggleOverlay();
}    

render() {
  //some code
  <button onClick={this.btnClick}>Click</button>
  //some code
}
```

Comment: Actually I can have multiple chat windows. The chat window is parent component called <View> and it have 2 child <Content> where messages are displayed and <Footer> where i have textbox and smiley button.  I need that when the smiley button in <Footer> is clicked the overlay with smileys open in the same chat window's <Content> component, so using store in this will make it quite bulky as i have to store states for every chat window which can be as many

Answer (score 0):

By doing so I got access to 'this' of `<Content>` in `<Footer>` component. Now I am not sure if morally I am doing the wrong thing, hurting the Reactjs motive of one-way binding. I'm using redux too, but how can I approach this with the help of store. Suggestions are highly appreciable coz i'm literally confused

`View.js`

```
class View extends Component {

  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.state = {
      thisOfContent: false    
    }
  }

  handleUpdateValue(newThisOfContent) {
    this.setState({
      thisOfContent: newThisOfContent
    })  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Content handleUpdateValue={this.handleUpdateValue.bind(this)}/>
        <Footer stateValue={this.state.thisOfChatWindowContent}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

`Content.js`

```
class Content extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.handleUpdateValue(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

`Footer.js`

```
class Footer extends Component {
  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.state = {
      showEmojiPicker: false,
    }
  }

  handleToggleEmojiPicker() {
    this.setState({
      showEmojiPicker: !this.state.showEmojiPicker,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <bootstrap.Button ref="targetEmojiPicker" bsSize="xsmall" onClick={this.handleToggleEmojiPicker.bind(this)}>
              <bootstrap.Glyphicon glyph="heart" />
            </bootstrap.Button>
            <bootstrap.Overlay
                show={this.state.showEmojiPicker}
                onHide={this.handleClose.bind(this)}
                container={this.props.stateValue}
                target={() => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.targetEmojiPicker)}
            >
              <EmojiModalCategories actions={this.props.actions}/>
            </bootstrap.Overlay>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Please update your original question as this is not an answer. :-)

Comment: Finally I have access to 'this' of <Content> in my <Footer>, thats what my question says.  If u want, i can make the question bulky with all this code added.