# Why is this.refs undefined?

Tags: reactjs

Why is `this.refs` undefined in the code below?

```
class NewItem extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.refs) //prints out undefined
    const name = this.refs.name.value;
    const description = this.refs.description.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/v1/items',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        item: {
          name: name,
          description: description
        }
      },
      success: (item) => {
        this.props.handleSubmit(item);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref='name' placeholder='Enter the name of the item' />
        <input ref='description' placeholder='Enter the description of the item' />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method is not bound to `this` when used as a function:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={event => this.handleClick(event)}>Submit</button>
```

or bind it in `constructor`:

```
constructor(props, context) {
   super(props, context);

   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this` to your `handleClick()` function, like this:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
```

or through the constructor, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

---

Though you should avoid using string literals in `refs`. This approach is [**deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873736/2030321).

> #### Legacy API: String Refs
>
> If you worked with React before, you might be
>   familiar with an older API where the `ref` attribute is a string, like
>   `"textInput"`, and the DOM node is accessed as `this.refs.textInput`. We
>   advise against it because string refs have [some issues](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/8333#issuecomment-271648615), are considered
>   legacy, and **are likely to be removed in one of the future releases**. If
>   you're currently using `this.refs.textInput` to access refs, we
>   recommend the callback pattern instead.

Instead do:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.nameInputRef;
  this.descriptionInputRef;
}

...

  <input ref={(el) => {this.nameInputRef = el;} placeholder='Enter the name of the item' />
  <input ref={(el) => {this.descriptionInputRef = el;} placeholder='Enter the description of the item' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You havens bind the functions. it should be done like this

```
class NewItem extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.refs) //prints out undefined
    const name = this.refs.name.value;
    const description = this.refs.description.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/v1/items',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        item: {
          name: name,
          description: description
        }
      },
      success: (item) => {
        this.props.handleSubmit(item);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref='name' placeholder='Enter the name of the item' />
        <input ref='description' placeholder='Enter the description of the item' />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Try using the ES6 features, The arrow functions to avoid this binding issue.
like this.

```
  handleClick =()=> {
    console.log(this.refs) //prints out undefined
    const name = this.refs.name.value;
    const description = this.refs.description.value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api/v1/items',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        item: {
          name: name,
          description: description
        }
      },
      success: (item) => {
        this.props.handleSubmit(item);
      }
    });
  }
```