# What is the proper way to use radio in React? The button gets frozen once checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using state to control my component, and I'm not sure what part of the following code is causing the code to button to freeze once checked.
This is the constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {

      firstName: '',
      
      inPerson: false,
      onlineMedium: true,
    };

  }
```

This function should handle change:

```
  handleFormChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;

 if (target.name === "inPerson" || target.name === "onlineMedium") {

      const value = !this.state[target.name]

      const name = target.name;
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    } 
else {
      const value = target.value;
      const name = target.name;

      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    }
  }
```

This renders the component:

```
  render() {

    return (
      <>
        <label className="tutor-add-label">
          First name
        <input
            className="tutor-add-input"
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={this.state.firstName}
            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
          />
        </label>
        <div className="medium">
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="online"
            name="onlineMedium"
            checked={this.state.onlineMedium}
            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="online">online</label>

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="person"
            name="inPerson"
            checked={this.state.inPerson}
            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="person">In person</label>
        </div>

      </>
    )
  }
```

Edit: As per the comment below, please let me know if there is another way to select/unselect radio that works better. I was following this http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-react-16/

Update: It seems that the click doesn't happen (after the first click)for some reason. Does that seem to point in any direction?

Comment: You're using a radio button and not a checkbox

Comment: first do this>>> if (name === "inPerson" || name === "onlineMedium")

Comment: because as per your if statement it will only check first value "inPerson"

Comment: I changed it to this>>> if (target.name === "inPerson" || target.name === "onlineMedium") , But it's still frozen

Comment: What would you suggest I use? I was following this site: http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-react-16/

Comment: @E.Reiner I think you can use **target.value** instead of **target.name**. I hope it'll work for you

Comment: Which line do you suggest i should change?

Comment: const value = !this.state[target.value]

Comment: @devd Thank you. I don't see any functional change. it seems like the click doesn't happen, so the function doesn't get called for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Changing the event handler from `onChange` to `onClick` and using the following to control state:

```
        if (target.name === "onlineMedium" || target.name === "inPerson") {
            if (event.target.checked && !this.state[target.name]) {
                this.setState({
                    [target.name]: true,
                })
            }
            else if (event.target.checked && this.state[target.name]) {
                this.setState({
                    [target.name]: false,
                })
            }

        }
```

Credit: it was inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57147343/10813256