# How to get value from radio form in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, react-hooks

I Have this form in one of my react components

```
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          className="form-check-input"
          value={3}
          name="priority"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label">High Priority</label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          value={2}
          className="form-check-input"
          name="priority"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label">Medium Priority</label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          value={1}
          className="form-check-input"
          name="priority"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label">Low Priority</label>
      </div>
```

I then have an onclick function on a button. I want to get the value of the radio form in my function. How do I do that? Is there a way to do it with the useRef hook?
Note: I am using functional components so any solution with class components will not help.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncheck radio buttons in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317663/uncheck-radio-buttons-in-react)

Comment: Use state to maintain the input values, and then access the state in your function when it's called.

Comment: Where would I say that the radio value is equal to the state? Would I state it in each radio input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created demo here, you could add onChange method to each input and then save inside in a state.

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-sinoussi-1t7fi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What happens when the OP adds that button he mentions in the question? How are you going to log the selected radio button? This is only half-an-answer.

Comment: You just need to add a button with onclick event then you manage state the onclick method use your values as you want, I have updated the demo so you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Use state to maintain the value of the selected radio input.

We add one listener to the parent element so we can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) which calls a function when it captures a change event from a child input element. When it's called it checks the clicked element is an input (radio) and then sets the state with its value.

The button simply logs the current state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise state
  const [ radio, setRadio ] = useState(0);

  // When the button is clicked log the current state
  function handleClick(e) {
    console.log(radio);
  }

  // When an element is clicked
  function handleChange(e) {

    // Grab the nodeName and value from
    // the clicked element
    const { nodeName, value } = e.target;

    // Because we're using event delegation (attaching
    // an event listener to a parent element and capturing
    // events from child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM)
    // we need to check to see if the clicked element is an input
    if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {

      // Set the state with the input value
      setRadio(value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onChange={handleChange}>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          className="form-check-input"
          value={3}
          name="priority"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label">High Priority</label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          value={2}
          className="form-check-input"
          name="priority"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label">Medium Priority</label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          value={1}
          className="form-check-input"
          name="priority"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label">Low Priority</label>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Show radio state</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
button { margin-top: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```