# How do I mock callbacks on a ref for testing in react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, video-reactjs

I am using video-react in a react application. I have to test a component that calls ref methods from a video-react component.
I hope to use enzyme so I can mount the component and check that I have called the ref method in ComponentDidMount.

Basically, how do I test that refs.player.seek gets called like it does below?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.player.seek(this.props.currentTime);
    this.refs.player.subscribeToStateChange(this.handlePlayerStateChange);
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using `this.refs` as that is deprecated in the latest versions of React. Instead use a callback pattern. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs/43873736#43873736) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).

Comment: @Chris Thank you for pointing that out, I have fixed my code and will update my examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [video-react](https://video-react.js.org/components/player/) requires refs to call play, pause and seek to my knowledge, I ended up using this pattern so I could mock my own ref callbacks hitting render methods.

https://medium.com/@planttheidea/never-render-in-react-testing-again-fc4bcfc2f71d

example component code:

```
export const createComponentWillReceiveProps = instance => ({seekTime, isPlaying, onSeekComplete}) => {
  const {paused} = instance.playerRef.getState().player;

  if (seekTime) {
    instance.playerRef.seek(seekTime);
    onSeekComplete();
  }
  if (isPlaying && paused) {
    instance.playerRef.play();
  }
  if (!isPlaying && !paused) {
    instance.playerRef.pause();
  }
};
```

...

```
componentWillReceiveProps = createComponentWillReceiveProps(this)
```

...

```
<VideoReactPlayer ref={el => this.playerRef = el} preload='auto' src={source}>
```

...

and the tests looked like this:

```
  it('calls playerRef.play when isPlaying prop is true & paused is true', () => {
    const instance = {playerRef: {play: jest.fn(), getState: () => ({player: {paused: true}})}};
    const componentWillReceiveProps = createComponentWillReceiveProps(instance);
    componentWillReceiveProps({isPlaying: true});
    expect(instance.playerRef.play).toBeCalled();
  });
```