# Using function param in this.refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I realise it's probably not even React issue and it's just me being confused beginner, but I'll ask question here anyway because I think I'm not understanding something.

I want to create a function that plays sound onClick event that's gonna be reusable.

Let's say I've got 2 audio tags in the render:

```
<audio ref="jammed" src={jammedSound}></audio>
<audio ref="budge" src={budgeSound}></audio>
```

and the function itself looks like this:

```
playSound(soundName){
  this.refs.soundName.play();
}
```

And it just won't work when I pass `playSound('jammed')` or `playSound('budge')`, I was trying to turn it to string in act of desperation, I was using curly brackets and brackets on soundName, nothing. I know it's probably JS issue I'm not understanding, I will be grateful for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax would be

```
this.refs[soundName].play()
```

Not sure about React though.

More info : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp

Comment: And it works. I was trying this.refs.[soundName].play(), I had no idea you have to drop the dot before the brackets. Thank you.

Comment: Please accept the answer, if satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [**using string literals as refs is deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs/43873736#43873736).

Instead, use functional refs:

```
<audio ref={(el) => this.jammedRef = el} src={jammedSound}></audio>
<audio ref={(el) => this.budgeRef = el} src={budgeSound}></audio>
```

and the function itself looks like this:

```
playSound(soundName){
  this[`${soundName}Ref`].play();
}
```