# Dynamically creating refs without strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

EDIT: We're using React 16.2.0, which is relevant to the question ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs)).

So far as I can tell, this is the accepted way to create a ref (at least for our version of react):

```
<div ref={(r) => { this.theRef = r; }}>Hello!</div>
```

And then it can be used something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.theRef) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
}
```

This works fine. However, if I want to create a *dynamically named ref*, say as part of a loop, how do I go about naming the ref?

Put in now obsolete terms, I would like something along these lines:

```
<div ref="{refName}">Hello!</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The post title is misleading. Please update.

Answer (score 1):

Try just:

```
<div ref={refName}>Hello!</div>
```

Comment: "using string literals in ref attributes is depreciated." [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs)

Answer (score 1):

For a map you need a key, so maybe you could just use that key to map to an object? Like so:

```js
this.myRefs = {}

doSomethingToRef = (key) => {
  this.myRefs[key].doSomething()
}

return (
  myValues.map(value => (
    <div key={value.key} ref = {r => {this.myRefs[value.key] = r}}>{...}</div>
  ))
)
```

Comment: This was my initial thought and it does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) like this:

Define the refName inside the class constructor:

```
this.refName = React.createRef()
```

Assign the ref in your element:

```
<div ref={this.refName} id="ref-name">Hello!</div>
```

To access the refName, use current:

```
this.refName.current
```

Example:

```
if (this.refName.current.id == 'ref-name') {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
```

**Update**

As per your comment, to use ref in older version, you may use just like this:

```
<div ref={(el) => this.refName = el} id="ref-name">Hello!</div>
{/* notice double quote is not used */}
```

To access:

```
this.refs.refName
```

Example:

```
if (this.refs.refName.id == 'ref-name') {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
```

To do it in more better way, you may use [callback pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

Comment: Oh, how I wish that were the case. Sadly, we are using 16.2 and I don't think that's an [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs)

Comment: updated... let me know if you have further question.

Comment: I get "createRef() is not a function." I don't think `React.createRef()` exists in React 16.2.0.

Comment: You don't need that with older version.

Comment: You may follow the callback ref linked in the post for its goodness.

Answer (score 0):

`[short-id][1]` might be a good candidate!

It has methods like:

```
ids.store('foo');  // "8dbd46"
ids.fetch('8dbd46');  // 'foo'
ids.fetch('8dbd46');  // undefined
ids.configure(Object conf)



$ npm install short-id
```

**RefsCmp.js**

```
var shortid = require('shortid');

const RefsList = (newrefs) = > (
   {newrefs.map(item => (
      <div ref={shortid.generate()}>Hello!</div>
   ))}
)

export default RefsList;
```