# React Native - ref's depreciation message

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a signature capture component (https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture) as part of a form.   I want to reset the form fields on submission via a reset function (ClearDutyRecord below) and need to reset the signature capture also as part of this process.

The component documentation (https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture) describes a reset function, which is ideal - but the method to call the function (using refs) is depreciated.  Looking around Stack Overflow I've found this post which explains the issue - [Deprecation warning using this.refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs) - but I'm unsure how to implement in RN - or whether there is a different approach I should now take - can anyhow offer any advice please?

This is my reset code currently:

```
clearDutyRecord = () => {

    this.setState({
      dutyRecordViewId: 'home',
      comments:'',
      signatureName:'',
    });
    this.refs["drSig"].resetImage();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeViewContainer');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a class component, You can use the `React.createRef()` solution - that is the most up-to-date way for class components.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

source: [reactjs docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)

React Native does use React.js inside, so don't worry about using the React in the Native environment - this is the same React (the stuff characteristic for browser-enviromnets are encapsulated in `react-dom` package).