# Why is this.refs deprecated in React class?

Tags: reactjs

Why is this.refs deprecated in React class?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs

Comment: Because modern React does not use `this.refs`, as per the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecation warning using this.refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs)