# React Native - How can I use ref after deprecation?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, ref

I'm using ref to show a custom alert but I've got a warning about deprecation so how can I use ref or any replacement of that?

```
<MyAlert ref="alert" />

this.refs.alert.open(
        errorBody,
        [
            {
                text: pbtn, onPress: () => {
                    this._home_call()
                }
            },
            { text: nbtn, onPress: () => { } }
        ],
        {
            type: 'alert',
            cancelable: false,
        },
    );
```

react version: 16.13.1

react-native version: 0.63.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecation warning using this.refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873511/deprecation-warning-using-this-refs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **functional components**

use ref hook in react

```
const alertRef = useRef(null);
```

then use it like

```
<MyAlert ref={alertRef />
```

for **class components**

create ref in constructor

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.alertRef= React.createRef();
 
}
```

then use it like

```
<MyAlert ref={(ref) => this.alertRef = ref} />
```